# Unable to display data transfer progress in multipeer connectivity framework

Tags: ios, swift, progress, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to print the progress of data transfer while using multipeer connectivity.
The `progress` information is available on the receiver side, in the `didStartReceivingResourceWithName` method and on the sender side, in the `sendResource` method.
Here is how I have implemented the receiver side:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print (progress)
        }
    }
```

And here is how I implemented the sender side:

```
func sendFileAction()->Progress{
        var filePath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "10MO", withExtension: "file")
        if mcSession.connectedPeers.count > 0 {

            do {
                let data =  try Data(contentsOf: filePath!)
                fileTransferProgressInSender = mcSession.sendResource(at: filePath!, withName: "filename", toPeer: mcSession.connectedPeers[0]) { (error) -> Void in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if error != nil {
                            print("Sending error: \(String(describing: error))")
                        }else{
                            print("sendAFile with no error "+"filename")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch let error as NSError {
                let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Send file error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
                present(ac, animated: true)
            }
        }
        return(fileTransferProgressInSender)
    }
```

The receiver function does display the `progress` only once, at the beginning.

```
<NSProgress: 0x1c0133740> : Parent: 0x0 / Fraction completed: 0.0000 / Completed: 0 of 10485760
```

And I can't figure out where I can call the return of `sendFileAction` to display the progress on the sender side.

Any help please?
Thanks.

Edit:
I tried with the following code:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
        startTime = Date()

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.endTransfer = false
            self.sendProgressBar.progress = 0.0
            self.updateProgress(progress: progress)
        }
    }

func updateProgress(progress:Progress){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            while !self.endTransfer {
                print (progress.fractionCompleted)
                self.sendProgressBar.progress = Float(progress.fractionCompleted)
            }
        }
    }
```

While the `print` gives real progress in the console, the progress bar jumps from 0 to 1 (reaches 1 before the `print` does).

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @CodeBender for the hint. Indeed, I needed a timer.
So here is how I did:

```
func session(_ session: MCSession, didStartReceivingResourceWithName resourceName: String, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, with progress: Progress) {
        startTime = Date()
        self.receptionProgress = progress
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.receptionTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateReceptionProgress), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
            self.receptionTimer.fire()
        }
    }
```

And the corresponding function:

```
@objc func updateReceptionProgress(){
        self.receptionProgressBar.progress = Float(self.receptionProgress.fractionCompleted)
        if self.receptionProgress.completedUnitCount >= self.receptionProgress.totalUnitCount{
            self.receptionTimer.invalidate()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For your receiver, you should capture the Progress variable to save, and then query it via a repeating timer.

Apple outlines the [basics here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity/mcsessiondelegate/1406965-session).

> An NSProgress object that can be used to cancel the transfer
>   or queried to determine how far the transfer has progressed.

For your sender, you are getting a progress indicator as a return from your function. Save it and query it with a timer to find status.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But I can't figure out where to call a function that prints that. I only have the `didFinishReceivingResourceWithName` and `didStartReceivingResourceWithName` and nothing else that is called in between.